# eval function doesn't work in python

Tags: python, string, eval

I have the following `code`:

```
tmpVariable = completeVariableName[filedsValueCounter];
tmpValue = fieldsValue[fieldsName[fieldsNameCounter]];
print eval ("'%s = \"%s\";' % (tmpVariable, tmpValue)");
```

Output of above code is :

```
self.name = "Peter"
```

Next line of eval function is :

```
print self.name
```

But It's output is :

```
None
```

**Question:** Where's my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For executing *statements* (such as the assignment in the question) in Python, you must use `exec()` because `eval()` works only for *expressions* (things that evaluate to values). Anyway, you don't need to evaluate the string in this case, `setattr` is the way to go:

```
setattr(self, 'name', 'Peter')
```

The above piece of code will have the same effect that this one:

```
self.name = 'Peter'
```

Comment: Oh, I need to retrive my `variable name` from a `list`.So i need to `exec` or `eval functions`.

Comment: I convert my `eval function` to `exec ('%s = \"%s\"' % (tmpVariable, tmpValue));` and got good answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`eval` is for expressions, but assignment is a statement.

However there is no need to use it here. You should use `setattr`.

Answer (score 1):

what if instead you wanted to create instances of a class using the replacement.

something like this:

```
class Class1:
    pass
class Class2:
    def generateParameters(self):
        self.parameters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
        for i in parameters:
        "self.{0} = class2()".format(i)
```

the idea being to generate a number of instances with specific varaibles